# Issue with fetching sorted records (CoreData)

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm having

two entities record and group.

one to many relationship, so each group can have multiple record.

in group -> `(relationship:arrRecord, Destination:record, Inverse:recordGroup)`

in record -> `(relationship:recordGroup, Destination:group, Inverse:arrRecord)`

I am able to fetch group and respective records. But I am not able to fetch group and respective records sorted by record field 'name'.

code:

```
let fetch: NSFetchRequest  = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "group")
if let fetchGroups = APP_DELEGATE.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetch, error: nil) as? [group]
{
 for group in fetchGroups
  {

    let sortDesc = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    let arrSorted = group.arrRecord.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDesc])
    print("arrSorted === \(arrSorted)") // sorted by name

    group.arrRecord = NSSet(array: arrSorted)
    print("NSSet(array: group.arrRecord) === \(group.arrRecord)") //not sorted by name

 } 
}
```

arrSorted is being sorted, but when converted back to NSSet, order resets :(

Comment: if you reassign the array to a set, then it is unsorted again. That's just how a set works, it's unsorted / unordered. Just use the sorted array.

Comment: Sets **by definition** are unsorted, so when you assign the results to a set, you will **always** have an unsorted collection.

Answer (score 1):

The 'To Many' relationship results in an `NSSet` (or `NSOrderedSet`, if you have checked 'ordered'), which is not a sorted collection.

You can use `- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors` to get a sorted `NSArray`.

Comment: Sets aren't sorted, and your managed object relationship isn't define as sorted, so you're not going to see sorting once you assign it back to the set. What's wrong with just using the array? What do you want to do with the sorted information?